# Magento UPS shipping option not showing up when customer logged in

Tags: magento, ups

OK, I've figured out my problem (see below) but need a new solution. I set a weight limit on UPS packages to 22lbs. I assumed orders over 22lbs would be split up into multiple packages. For example the total order could be 33lbs, I need shipping to be calculated on one package at 22lbs and one at 11bs.

Instead of calculating shipping on two or more packages the UPS option is disabled. Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Original Question---
The UPS XML module is not showing up as an option when I try to check out when logged in as a registered user. However, when I check out as a guest the UPS options show up. Can anyone help me out with this? I did change a lot of the .xml files but I don’t think I messed with anything to disable specific shipping options for registered users. Anyway help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, 
Gary